# Overriding model name of a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

It would be nice if there was a more elegant way of doing this, given these models:

```
@forum_topic = ForumTopic.find(1)
@forum_topic.forum_sub_topics.each do |fst|  #it would be nicer if one could just type @forum_topic.sub_topics.each...
  #
end
```

It seems redundant to have to include forum_ in front of sub_topics because I know I'm dealing with a forum_topic.  I could change the name of the table/model to SubTopic but that is a bit generic and could possibly come up somewhere in the application.  **Is there a way to override the name of the methods created on ForumTopic for the has_many association?**

Models:

```
class ForumTopic...
  has_many :forum_sub_topics
end

class ForumSubTopic...
end
```

Ah the answer is right here.   Thanks! :)
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
has_many :sub_topics, :class_name => "ForumSubTopic"
```

##### Reference

[ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods has_many - see under Options](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can specify whatever association name you want and still tell it to use your `ForumSubTopic` class:

```
class ForumTopic
  has_many :sub_topics, :class_name => "ForumSubTopic", :foreign_key => "forum_sub_topic_id"
end
```